# What is the proper connection method for this LiPo battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I salvaged this LiPo battery from an old bluetooth speaker. I'm wondering how to properly test the connections to ensure I charge it correctly and how to wire it into the Arduino project I'm working on.

[image]

Battery Specs: 3.7V, 6,000mAh, 22.2Wh

It has a five pin connector: 2 x Red, 1 x White, 2 x Black.

I'm also sharing a picture of the board it was previously connected to. It looks to me like the contacts for each pair of red and black wires are soldered together.

[image]

Can I just treat this as a normal three pin LiPo connector? How best to determine what the white lead is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery is a 1S, so the white wire is likely a temperature sensor of some kind. The black and red pairs are almost certainly connected (although I don't know why they've done this).

Check with a multimeter but you will probably see that the backs are shorted together as are the reds, and there's 3.5-4.2V between red and black. In that case I would just ignore the white wire and treat it like a regular 1S.

It's possible there's some other circuitry in there but I doubt it.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was hoping to hear. I'm seeing almost exactly 3.7V on each combination of Red and Black. Same when I short black to black and red to red and test those together.